# Encode Get-Parameter twice for Azure Function

Tags: c#, rest, azure-functions, urlencode

I am facing a strange behavior with my Azure Function and a Get-Parameter value containing a backslash. Here is my example code:

**Azure Function**

```
[FunctionName("MyHTTPFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> MyHTTPFunction(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "v1/myobjects/names/{myobjectname}/property")] HttpRequest req,
    string myobjectname,
    ILogger log,
    ExecutionContext executionContext)
{
    try
    {
        myobjectname = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myobjectname);
        return new OkObjectResult("ok");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult("exception");
    }
}
```

**What is happening**

The parameter value for {myobjectname} is "A\B", so the base url would look like:

```
https://MyFancyAzureServer.com/api/v1/myobjects/names/A\B/property
```

of course this will not work (neither on server nor in local debug) because of the backslash. So I decided to encode the {myobjectname} value via HttpUtility:

```
myobjectname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myobjectname);
```

which will replace the backslash with "%5c" and change the url to:

```
https://MyFancyAzureServer.com/api/v1/myobjects/names/A%5cB/property
```

and from now on the behavior confuses me. On localhost, the encoded parameter is working fine. The azure function app on server returns "not found" for that url. After some try and error I accidentally did encode the {myobjectname} twice:

```
myobjectname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myobjectname);
myobjectname = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myobjectname);
```

so the "A\B" was replaced with "A%255cB" and the url was changed to:

```
https://MyFancyAzureServer.com/api/v1/myobjects/names/A%255cB/property
```

and surprise, surprise: It works! On the server and in local debug.

So the final question: Why do I have to encode my parameter value twice for the function on the server while encoding once is enough for local debug? What is the difference? Any UrlEncoding settings in the function app? Maybe just a small fact I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am try to reproduce this issue. but its not working on both case.

slash replace with %2f and replace with %255c.

slash replace with %255c on server side.
[image]

slash replace with %2f server side.
[image]

Right ways is you can pass slash values with two parameters.
[image]

its work fine locally.
[image]

and its work fine on server side also.
[image]